# python failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!

Tags: python, selenium

Есть парсер на python + seleniumwire.
Парсер должен работать круглосуточно, с периодичной проверкой наличия новых данных.
Все работает без ошибок, до момента сборки pyinstaller'ом для передачи файла *.exe заказчику.
Команда для сборки: `pyinstaller --onefile main.py`.
Собственно заказчик запускает парсер и тут начинаются неопределенности в виде необработанного исключения, причем скрипт может проработать то час, то более суток и скрипт падает `failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!`.
Traceback в основном этот: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`
Что то ничего из найденной информации не помогает.. Я грешу на нестабильный интернет (заказчик живет в Крыму), но ничего придумать не могу, как можно исключить падение скрипта.

Функция:

```
def get_html(url, proxies):
proxy = {
    'proxy': {
        'https': 'https://' + proxies,
    }
}
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
options.add_argument(
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36")
if proxies != '':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=options, seleniumwire_options=proxy)
else:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=options)
try:
    driver.get(url)
except:
    pass
data = driver.page_source

return data
```

Comment: Если исключение известно почему бы его не перехватить?

Comment: @Александр, строчка driver.get(url) помещена в обработчик try - except, причем без указания конкретного исключения.

Comment: Вы бы код приложили,  быстрее бы ответ получили.

Comment: Хорошо бы ещё полный стектрейс посмотреть, возможно падает не там, где вам кажется должно падать, не в том месте кода. А если в том, то перехват должен таки сработать.

Comment: @CrazyElf Добавил функцию в пост.

Comment: Ну хорошо, поймали вы исключение и сделали `pass` (ужасная практика на самом деле). И что будет на строчке `data = driver.page_source` в этом случае? Состояние `driver` в этот момент мягко говоря неопределённое, и что он вернёт - да кто его знает. Может тут эксепшен и бросается. Мой вам совет - оборачивайте лучше вызов `get_html` в `try`, ловите эксепшен и как-то по умному его обрабатывайте, пропускайте итерацию или что. По логике вашей программы. `pass` - это не выход вообще, логика программы должна учитывать ошибки. Конкретнее сложно сказать, не видя код, который вызывает `get_html`

Comment: Можно и по-простому, вместо `pass` хотя бы делать `return ""` и проверять при вызове, что вернулось, не пустая ли страница. Но делать с обработкой ошибок что-то нужно.

Comment: @CrazyElf `pass` я вписал для заглушки, так как это пока что процесс тестирования. Кстати, сейчас заметил, что скрипт падает на моменте запуске драйвера `driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=options)`. Наверное, Как вариант сделаю закрытие браузера после `page_sourse` или вообще инициировать драйвер при запуске скрипта.

Comment: Нужно как-то так писать блоки кода, чтобы в случае ошибки можно было выйти из этого блока с ошибкой, запустить его заново, и там всё нормально инициализировалось и заработало.

Comment: @CrazyElf да, спасибо. Позже что нибудь поколдую.